# Do I have to go into my catkin workspace and source devel/setup.bash every time before I can use my launch file?

Tags: roslaunch, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I would like to be able to open a terminal and type roslaunch .launch **OR** roslaunch  .launch and have it launch. Currently I have to cd into my catkin workspace and do "source devel/setup.bash" EVERY time I open a new terminal. How can I make it launch without having to do this every time? Thanks in advance for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239131/do-i-have-to-go-into-my-catkin-workspace-and-source-devel/setup.bash-every-time-before-i-can-use-my-launch-file?/) by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can source your setup file from within any directory, i.e. you do not have to change to your workspace's directory to do this.

You can add the `source /path/to/workspace/devel/setup.bash` to your `~/.bashrc` file. Though it could be confusing if in the future you forgot you did this, and your shell unexpectedly has that workspace sourced. If you add the line to your `~/.bashrc` so that it is done every time you open a shell, then you might also consider printing a message to remind yourself that this is happening.

Also, I actually prefer setting aliases rather than automatically sourcing workspaces when I open a new terminal, because I work with many workspaces at once typically. If you don't then perhaps you'd prefer just adding it directly to your `~/.bashrc`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on 2016-07-08**:
Thanks for the help! How do you go about setting up aliases? I'm pretty new to ROS/Ubuntu, so not sure if I'll be working on multiple workspaces at once any time soon, but it would be nice to know for the future. :)

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-07-08**:
Here's an example @Morefoam: `alias ros="source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash"` (you place that in your `~/.bashrc` file) Similarly for your catkin workspaces, like William mentioned. Make sure you call them in the right order.